# Load Fragment in Activity OnCreate

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, load

**Problem**: Switching from fragment 1 to fragment 2, the switch happens, but both are visible. (fragment 2 comes into focus)

Fragment 1 is MenuFragment
Fragment 2 is GameFragment

I believe this is happening because my fragment 1 is included in my main activity.xml

```
   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/menu_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_menu">
    </fragment>
```

The code above in main.xml loads the fragment into the main activity. Whenever I replace the menu fragment with game fragment using this code:

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) 
{
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.gameview_layout, gameFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.toString());
    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

the game fragment appears and overlays above the menu fragment. How do I get the menu fragment to disappear? I'm sure an easy fix would be makeVisible(false) or something similar, but I believe the real problem is programming in the xml file to include the MenuFragment in the first place.

**Question**: How do I program in the main.java class to load a fragment on create?

I want to do this, so I can program it to load fragment 1 (MenuFragment) first without it already being there. The only reason both are visible is because fragment 1 is included in my main.xml

Comment: How do you **dynamically create a fragment initially?** I created Fragment 2 dynamically, but Fragment 1 (MenuFragment) is statically created and that's why it stays there. I used the same replaceFragment code to put Fragment 1 dynamically in the view and it worked, but the findViewByIds made it crash. I had to comment that out, and now i can't test the onClickListener to see if it goes to Fragment 2

Comment: Fixed everything.  

**SOLUTION:**  
1) Do NOT statically program fragment in xml file
2) use the code [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of creating two fragments, you should create a single FrameLayout(or any other) and replace the frame layout during the switching as in example below.

**XML**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**Kotlin**

```
fun replaceFragment(fragment:Fragment){
    supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frameContainer, fragment)
            .commit()
}
```

**Java**

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameContainer, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.toString());
    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: FrameLayout being in the main.xml? If I do that, the same problem occurs... How do I put the fragment in the FrameLayout on launch?

Comment: This is a good answer for giving me direction. My main problem ended up being that the app crashed because of an onclicklistener and finding the button in the fragment. I ended up having to find the button and implement a listener in the fragment java file, not the main java file. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to know I am giving direction. Keep doing android development. You are doing well I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use some layout like LinearLayout or FrameLayout as a container for your fragments and in onCreate make something like

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.menu_fragment, MenuFragment.getInstance())
    .commit();
```

and rename container id to "@+id/fragmentContainer" or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

In your fragment layout xml add a **background** color to solve the problem

Comment: woah, that worked. I wonder why... it seems as if the layout not being a frame container isn't a problem. I hate using framelayouts because relative layouts are so simple for me. I tried messing with the constraint layout too, couldn't figure it out. Guess I could always put a relative layout int he frame layout

Comment: **All the color does is overlay on top of it. I want it to replace the fragment**