# How to load fragment when onNavigationItemSelected is triggered?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I created new tab project on Android and it gave me the following in my `MainActivity`:

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
//                    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PostActivity.class);
//                    startActivity(i);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I want to load different layout. My question is, what class should the fragment classes extend? is it `Fragment`? or `FragmentActivity`?

and how can I load it in the `onNavigationItemSelected`? The old way was `return new FragmentName()` but it won't work since the `onNavigationItemSelected` returns `boolean` type

Comment: create one fragment container in your activity and on Menu item click load the desired fragments. And you can extend the fragment classes with Fragment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load Fragment in Activity OnCreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017757/load-fragment-in-activity-oncreate)

Comment: @deathangel908 thank you, it is duplicate, I voted to close

Answer (score 0):

Same like navigation drawer create layout with frame layout and call fragment that  i send in below.
inplace of

mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);

call fragment

```
 Fragment fragment = new Fragment() ;
                fragment.setCategoryItemListener(MainActivity.this);
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, "HOME").commit();
```

Comment: What class should the Fragment Class extend? Fragment or FragmentActivity?

Answer (score 0):

call this function in switch case and pass fragment object

```
public void moveFragment(Fragment fragment, String fragmentname) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
       fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.abc_fade_in,
                R.anim.abc_fade_out);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame,
                fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

    }
```

Only use fragment not fragment Activity

Comment: the fragment class should extend either Fragment or FragmentActivity class. am I right?